# Including Script Files in an R Extension Package

Tags: r, package

I'm creating an R package and I need it to include a couple of non R script files which get called by one of my functions. I need these script files to be distributed with the package, naturally. So that leaves me with two questions:

1. a) In which directory of the package
   tree should I place these files? b) Is that location mandatory or just convention?
2. Do I need to change any other
   settings or configurations or will
   they just get copied to the
   directory mentioned in #1 and then I
   can figure out the path using
   system.file()?

I've tried to find the answer in the [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html) document, but it didn't jump out at me. And, of course, I didn't read the whole thing. Am I being too honest here?

Comment: Shell script that bootstraps a new version of R into Amazon EMR. The package will upload that to S3 then have the EMR nodes run it. I just need access to it so that I can upload it to S3.

Comment: You know that will make you package OS dependent, right?

Comment: the script never runs on the machine on which the package is installed. The script runs on Amazon's EMR machines which always run Debian. 

But my source is currently platform dependent for other reasons, the greatest of which is my apathy toward other platforms. Maybe someone can port it later ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you want either `exec/` at the top-level (even though that is labeled 'still experimental, or subdirectory of `inst` as everything in `inst/` gets copied verbatim into the package.

A quick example from the packages I have expanded in source is [gdata](http://cran.r-project.org/package=gdata) which has `inst/perl`, `inst/xls` and `inst/bin`.  These you could then call from R itself by computing the path of the installed package using `system.file()`.

Comment: Bingo! And now that I know what I am looking for, it's covered in the very fine documentation right here: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-subdirectories

Comment: inst/ is going to be what I use, I believe. I just want a payload carried over unmolested and un-executed.

Comment: That'll do. I hope you also implement the `withLasers=TRUE` option for Shane while you're at it.

Comment: I default `withLaster=T` and `withFrigginLasers=F`. I could be convinced to change the defaults if plied with enough beer.